# Image appearing multiple times on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm drawing a simple dynamic canvas and I'm wondering how I can make the .png file in my drawImage method appear like 40 times at different places on my canvas at the same time?
Thanks beforehand! :)

Thank you all very much for your reply! This is as far as I've gotten now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx;
var imgBg;
var imgDrops;
var x = 40;
var y = 0;
    function setup() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasRegn');

        if (canvas.getContext) {
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        setInterval('draw();', 36);
        imgBg = new Image();
        imgBg.src = 'dimma.jpg';

        imgDrops = new Image();
        imgDrops.src = 'drop.png';

        }
    }

function draw() {
    drawBackground();

    for(var i=0; i <= 40; i++) {    
    ctx.drawImage (imgDrops, x, y);
    y += 3;
    if(y > 450)
            y = -20;
        x=Math.random()*600;
    }

}

function drawBackground(){  
    ctx.drawImage(imgBg, 0, 0);
}
</script>
```

My problem is now that the images are jumping all over the place... I want them "falling" down slowly from above and coming back around:(

Comment: I've tried using the transformers translate and save. I've also been looking around the net for some kind of loop, but can't get my head around it...

Comment: A bit of your code would come in handy

Comment: You should edit your question with the code; it's not very readable as a comment (since comments eliminate line breaks).

Comment: Well, of course they are jumping around. You change the x value every time. You need to maintain the 'dropables' as an array of objects which contain the x and y values, and you can increment the y value on each update for each object. Something like this; http://jsfiddle.net/pyzHP/17/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/D83uC/10/

I made it to explain some basics of canvas to a friend recently. Although I'm using shapes instead of .png files I think the loop you are looking for is the same.

The key bit of code being this loop below

```
setInterval(function(){
  // clear stage
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].move(balls);
  }
}, 1000/FPS)
```

FPS is a variable, and .move() is a function that calculated new co-ordinates for and then re-draws the ball object.

I think it might simply not clearing the 'stage' `context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);`

**EDIT** Perhaps that example had too much going on in it to be useful.

Please see a much earlier version http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/D83uC/2 that simple animates the ball. The main point remains though, **you need to clear the canvas if you don't want the 'trails'**

Think of canvas like windows paint, not flash. The things you have drawn aren't editable objects. You need to redraw the whole thing each time. (Unless you use a JS library that makes things seem more like flash - but I'm guessing you want to learn without helper libraries at first)

As I said, I was explaining canvas to someone recently and you can see the various stages between the two links I've sent you by changing the number on the end of the URL http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/D83uC/3 
http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/D83uC/4 
etc.

**EDIT2**

Or if I've misunderstood, post a jsfiddle and let us know what is wrong with it

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think that's too complicated. Is there no easier way? This is as far as I've gotten now, but now all of the drops appear on the same spot:

    function draw() {
     drawBackground();
  for (var i=0; i < 40; i++){  
  ctx.drawImage(imgDrops, x, y);
  
  }
  y += 3;
  if(y > 450){
               y = -20;
        x=Math.random()*600;
            }
  }

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: http://edumax.org.ro/extra/new/imagetut/
You can get the code here: http://edumax.org.ro/extra/new/imagetut/script.js

The relevant part is this:

```
function draw_image(){
//draw one image code
}
window.onload = function () {
   for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<10;j++){
        draw_image(10+i*40, 10+j*40, 40, 40);
    }
}  
}
```

This code only explains the concept, it will not work by itself, for a full version check the link above.